# How to compare an object to another object within a vector?

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods, vector

With this function I am trying to see if myPlayerUp (a Player Object) is equal to any of the player objects within a vector of players, myPlayers. It is saying that "The method myPlayers(int) is undefined for the type" even though the vector is used above. Am I going about comparing this the wrong way? Here is the whole class

```
package model;

//import yahtzee.model.boolean;
import java.util.Vector;
//import yahtzee.model.int;
//import yahtzee.model.void;
import model.Player;

public class YahtzeeEngine {

  public static final int MAX_ROLLS= 0;

  private Vector<Player> myPlayers;

  private Roller myRoller;

  private Player myPlayerUp;

  private int myNumberRollsUsed;

  public Vector  myPlayer;

  public YahtzeeEngine(int numPlayers) {
      myPlayers = new Vector<Player>(numPlayers);

      myNumberRollsUsed = 0;
  }

  public void startGame() {
      int i;
      for(i = 0; i<=myPlayers.size(); i++){
          myPlayers.add(new Player());
      }
      this.selectPlayerUp(myPlayers.get(0));
      myNumberRollsUsed = 0;
      myRoller = new Roller();
      myPlayerUp = new Player();
  }

  public void selectPlayerUp(Player player) {
      myPlayerUp = player;
  }

  public void switchPlayerUp() {
 int x;
 int y;
 for(x = 0; x<=myPlayers.size(); x++){
 if(myPlayerUp == myPlayers(x) && x < myPlayers.size()-1){
 y = x;
 }
 if(myPlayerUp == myPlayers(x) && x == myPlayers.size()-1){
 y = 0;
 }
 }
 myPlayerUp = myPlayers(y);
  }

  public boolean incrementRollsUsed() {
      myNumberRollsUsed++;
  return false;
  }

  public void resetNumberRollsUsed() {
      myNumberRollsUsed = 0;
  }

  public Roller getRoller() {
  return myRoller;
  }

  public Player getPlayerUp() {
  return myPlayerUp;
  }

  public Vector<Player> getPlayers() {
  return myPlayers;
  }

  public int getNumberRollsUsed() {
  return myNumberRollsUsed;
  }

  public String toString() {
  return null;
  }

}
```

And here is where it is giving me the errors on the "myPlayers" vector

```
 public void switchPlayerUp() {
 int x;
 int y;
 for(x = 0; x<=myPlayers.size(); x++){
 if(myPlayerUp == myPlayers(x) && x < myPlayers.size()-1){
 y = x;
 }
 if(myPlayerUp == myPlayers(x) && x == myPlayers.size()-1){
 y = 0;
 }
 }
 myPlayerUp = myPlayers(y);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectors aren't functions.  You want `get()`.

Also, use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I have to use vectors for this

Comment: because it is the code generated from what the professor gave us

Comment: `Vector` has thread safety and `ArrayList` doesn't.  Certainly, `ArrayList` is preferable in most cases, for no other reason than performance.  It is not preferable if thread safety is required.  It's not clear from the question whether the `YahtzeeEngine` needs to be thread safe.

Comment: @user2909132: Tell your professor that he should not be using `Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `indexOf` method of the `Vector` class.  Something like

```
y = myPlayers.indexOf(myPlayerUp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access elements in a vector like this `myPlayers(x)`, however this is saying call a method `myPlayers`, which takes an int, and there is no such method.

What you want to do is:

```
myPlayers.get(x);
```

Also for comparison you may want to use `equals` if you want to compare that two players are the same in terms of their fields, not their reference.
You would need to override `equals`

Answer (score 0):

To add to what SLaks said, in Java, we test for equality between Objects by overriding the `equals()` method.

`==` will not give you the result you want and should only be used to compare primitives for equality.

Comment: No.  The equals method is not needed here.  All of the `Player` objects in use come from the vector, so it's OK to use ==.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `equals` on your Player class as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (in fact, you should always implement `equals` and `hashCode` on your custom classes. Your IDE probably can do it automatically). Then you can simply call

```
numPlayers.contains(myPlayer);
```

This will return true is the player is in the `Vector`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is how `contains` works.

If you need the position instead, then you use `indexOf` as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Vector.html):

```
numPlayers.indexOf(myPlayer);
```

If the result is nonnegative, then that's where the player is. Otherwise, the player isn't there.

By the way, is using `Vector` still a thing?

Comment: No.  OP needs the position in the `Vector` where the thing is found.  so `indexOf` is needed, not `contains`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Made the edit. I guess I was just so flummoxed seeing `Vector`. It would be like seeing a stagecoach in New York City.

Comment: Yeah, not enough people use `Vector`.  They use `ArrayList`, then spend hours chasing down concurrency bugs when they ship their class to a multi-threaded environment.  But `Vector` is not deprecated, and it occasionally has its uses.